# Why the unit circle in $\mathbf{R^2}$ has one dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles, convex-optimization

When I was reading 'Convex Optimization, Stephen Boyd', I was wondering of following steps

- Consider the unit circle in $\mathbf{R^2}$, $i.e.$, $\{x\in\mathbf{R^2}|x^2_1+x^2_2=1\}$. Its affine hull is all of $\mathbf{R^2}$, so its affine dimension is two. By most definitions of dimension, however, the unit circle in $\mathbf{R^2}$ has dimension one.

I understood the affine hull of unit circle has dimension two because the all of values of affine hull is in $\mathbf{R^2}$. 
But still I don't understand why the unit circle in $\mathbf{R^2}$ has one dimension.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you believe that a line has dimension $1$ (by most reasonable definitions of dimension, at least)? If so, then a circle is locally the same as a line in a lot of meaningful senses.

Comment: $S^2$ can be represented by $e^{i\theta}$, which just needs one variable.

Comment: @gaoxinge That would be $S^1$!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define dimension first, but intuitively the dimension is how many independent directions you can walk along if you were on the surface. On a circle, you can only walk back and forth along the circle, you don't have any other choice, so its dimension is $1$. More precisely, a circle is locally homeomorphic to a line, which has dimension $1$.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know what definition of dimension you are using, so I cannot give a precise answer. But let me say this: As a general principle, each new independent equation introduced in a system of equations cuts down the dimension of the solution space by $1$. This is true for systems of linear equations by elementary linear algebra, but it's also true for algebraic varieties in general, where the precise statement takes the form of the [Krull principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem).

Since $\mathbf R^2$ has dimension $2$, and the circle is determined by a single equation, it must have dimension $2-1=1$.

Comment: This works well over algebraically closed field but not over the reals: A point in the plane is given by one algebraic equation $x^2+y^2=0$. You also need to invoke the fact that circle is given preimage of a regular value of one function.

Comment: @studiosus Yes indeed.