# Are planes in $3$-dimensions two-dimensional?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> Are planes in $3$-dimensions two-dimensional?

The reason I ask is because mathematically the $xy$-plane exists in $3$D space but appears to be $2$D, but how can something $2$D be in $3$D space? I therefore conclude that a plane in $3$D space must have a thickness that is infinitesimal. Isn't this a contradiction, though, since planes have a thickness of that of a point and since a point has no thickness neither does the plane?

Comment: Look up for-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Planes_embedded_in_3-dimensional_Euclidean_space

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297857/are-circles-and-lines-in-two-space-one-dimensional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to mention when talking about the term *dimension* is that in mathematics there is an exact definition of this term. So, when we speak about dimensions, the first thing to do is to define what *dimension* means. For the kind of geometry you use, the definition of the term *dimension* from a mathematical field called *linear algebra* is the appropriate one. In this sense, *dimension* is a property of so-called *vector spaces*.

- Let's start by defining the term *vector space* (I will only consider vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ here to simplify things): The set

  $V=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mid x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}\}$

  is a vector space of dimension $n$. Please note: Not every vector space is of this form!
- Remark: From school you may know $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is a vector space of dimension 2) and $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is a vector space of dimension 3).
- The interesting question is: Given a subset $U$ of $V$, what is its dimension? We can only define what the dimension of $U$ is if $U$ itself is a vector space. $U\subseteq V$ is a vector space, if and only if there exist $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m\in V$ such that

  $U=\{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_mv_m\mid a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\in\mathbb{R}\}$
- Now two cases can occur: Either $U=V$ holds or $U\subset V$ holds. For $U=V$, the dimension of $U$ is obviously $n$. For $U\subset V$, we still have to define what dimension means.
- For defining the term *dimension*, we first have to define what *linearly independent* means: A set $W=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\},W\subseteq V$ is called *linearly independent*, if the equation

  $a_1w_1+a_2w_2+\ldots+a_mw_m=\mathbf{0}\quad(a_i\in\mathbb{R})$

  only holds for $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_m=0$.
- For example: The set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(3,2,0)\}$ is not linearly independent, because

  $3\cdot (1,0,0)+2\cdot (0,1,0)-(3,2,0)=(0,0,0)$

  On the other hand, the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is linearly independent, because

  $a_1\cdot (1,0,0)+a_2\cdot (0,1,0)=(0,0,0)$ implies $a_1=a_2=0$.
- Now we can define what dimension means:

  $U=\{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_mv_m\mid a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\in\mathbb{R}\}$

  has dimension $m$ if and only if $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m\}$ is a linearly independent set.
- Example (continuation of the above example):

  $\{a_1(1,0,0)+a_2(0,1,0)+a_3,(3,2,0)\mid a_1,a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{R}\}$

  is the same vector space as

  $\{a_1(1,0,0)+a_2(0,1,0)\mid a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$;

  its dimension is 2 (because $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is linearly independent).
- Remark: Given a vector space $U$, its dimension is unique.
- Remark: If $n$ is the dimension of $V$, $m$ is the dimension of $U$ and $U\subseteq V$, then $m\leq n$ holds.
- If $U\subseteq V$ is a vector space and $v_0\in V$,

  $U^\prime=v_0+U=\{v_0+a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_mv_m\mid a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\in\mathbb{R}\}$

  is called an affine vector space. The dimension of $U'$ is defined as the dimension of $U$.

In the above points, we have defined the term *dimension* for vector spaces. What remains to be done is to show how vector spaces are related to basic geometry:

- Any point can be represented by an affine vector space $\{v_0\}\subseteq V$. Therefore, points have dimension 0.
- Any line can be represented by an affine vector space $\{v_0+a_1v_1\mid a_1\in\mathbb{R}\}$, where $v_0\in V$ and $v_1\in V$ are given. Therefore, lines have dimension 1. (The set contains the points that lie on the line.)
- Any plane can be represented by an affine vector space $\{v_0+a_1v_1+a_2v_2\mid a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$, where $v_0\in V$, $v_1\in V$ and $v_2\in V$ are given and $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent. (The set contains the points that lie in the plane.)

Please note: There is no limit on how big a dimension can be; for example, you can also define vector spaces of dimension 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is two dimensional. We define the dimension of a vector space (or a subspace of a vector space) to be the cardinality of a minimum spanning set. Any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as the span of two vectors.